# Validating Apex method parameters

Tags: apex, validation, bestpractice

Is it a good practice to validate method parameters in Apex methods? In C# and Java you generally validate against nulls and throw argument exceptions to prevent usage errors. I don't seem to see that in any SF examples.

```
 public static void DoStuff(string foo)
 {
    if(IsBlank(foo))
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException('foo cannot be null');
    }

    //Do stuff here knowing the argument is not null
 }
```

Should the code above be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be avoided as much as possible. An exception typically takes 0.05 seconds to unwind the stack. If you have such code in a trigger that operates on 200 records, you could easily generate 10 seconds of CPU time just to generate the exceptions, not including handling them. This would violate governor limits for synchronous code.

It is much better to allow the caller to guard against such violations, if necessary. This drastically improves code performance for the critical path at the risk of hard transaction failures (e.g. it is aborted). If a developer is aware that such exceptions may be generated, they should code for this in unit tests to make sure their code does not fail.

However, there are times that exceptions are unavoidable, such as when trying to reserve email capacity (found in the Messaging class). During these times, you should use the exceptions as necessary, but not any more frequently than that. Exceptions are simply too costly to use as a normal means of communication in a critical path. Any logic errors should preferentially be caught by unit tests so the appropriate guards can be put in place.

This advice is also applicable to situations where you're calling system library code. For example, some String methods will throw a NullPointerException when used. You should simply check if the value that would be passed is null rather than writing a try-catch handler to catch the exception. As a rule of thumb, prevention of generating exceptions is preferable to handling them.

Comment: I feel like this answer is a little bit of a contradiction. On one hand, I agree that just calling a method in a try/catch block isn't ideal, isn't it still a good idea to throw exceptions if the arguments don't meet the criteria you're after? The string NullPointerException is a good example. You'd always check your string variable before calling the string method so that the exception won't be thrown, but the exception is there to ensure the method only acts on good data and behaves in a consistent and expected manner. It provides good feedback that you're not checking your variables first.

Comment: @NickCook It's okay to use exceptions when you need to break out of deeply nested logic, but is too costly to use everywhere for every argument. Most of time, simply allowing a NullPointerException to occur is preferable to checking to see if you'd cause a NullPointerException then throw an ArgumentNullException. Developers calling your methods should be doing any appropriate checks. In all cases, trying to throw your own exceptions requires more code, and in most cases, requires more CPU time than allowing the system to throw for you.

Comment: @NickCook Looking through the code I've written, I end up writing about one custom exception a year, and it's always because I need to either break out of rather deeply nested code or provide additional information that an Exception won't provide (e.g. a AWSServiceException to provide the web service callout response error). I was rather careful to note that there are exceptions to the rule, but they should be exceptionally rare in most cases.

Comment: I've generally used exceptions a bit more than that, but usually because a generic exception can be hard to diagnose, or the business rules on why certain data requirements are being enforced may not be clear. Maybe this is what you mean by deeply nested logic.I like the performance part of the answer though.  It's not a consideration I've really given to it before.